# Java 8 stream more simple

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of some objects. Those objects have some fields and other stuff inside that changes over time. I want to get certain elements inside the list that have some value equal to `true`. I take that object and I want to use it somewhere else.

When the list doesn't contain an object with that element, I get an exception and my application crashes. So I am using a really strange code to avoid this and I want to know, if there is something more simple and better than this.

```
public class CustomObject{
    private String name;
    private boolean booleanValue;
    //Getters and setters... 
}

//Somewhere else I have the list of objects.
List<CustomObject> customList = new ArrayList<>();
//Now... here I am using this strange piece of code I want to know how to change.
if (customList.stream().filter(CustomObject::getBooleanValue).findAny().isPresent()) {
    customList.stream().filter(CustomObject::getBooleanValue).findAny().get().... //some custom stuff here.
}
```

As you can see I am doing really ugly code here: calling twice the same method.
I tried something like

```
CustomObject customObject = customList.stream().filter.....
```

and checking if that object is not null but it is not doing what I wanted.

Comment: Why don't you just store the `Optional` in a variable?

Comment: Because I don't want to use optional

Comment: What? Why? You're already using it.

Comment: Is there only ever one object in the `Stream` where `booleanValue` is `true`?

Comment: You shouldn't be calling get() unconditionally; you should be using one of the safe methods like orElse, orElseThrow, or ifPresent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just use [`ifPresent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresent-java.util.function.Consumer-) to get rid of `isPresent` and `get` if it is true:

```
customList.stream()
          .filter(CustomObject::getBooleanValue)
          .findAny()
          .ifPresent(customObject -> { /* do something here */ });
```

If a value was found by `findAny()`, the specified consumer will be invoked, otherwise, nothing will happen.

Comment: Thanks, that was exacly what I was looking for !